# Issue running Open Broadcaster Software (OBS Studio)

Tags: opengl

I am trying to run OBS Studio but I only have Open GL version 2.0 and the documentation states that minimum version is 3.3. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and spent hours running through websites trying to upgrade my opengl version to 3.3 unsucessfully. Can anyone help? or otherwise are there any alternatives to OBS to record video (e.g. recording streaming video from zoom)? I am really new to linux.

The error I am getting when I try to run obs is the one below.
Thanks

---

when I run `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` I get

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset (CTG)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

***************************************************************
ERROR

Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz
info: CPU Speed: 1401.118MHz
info: Physical Cores: 2, Logical Cores: 2
info: Physical Memory: 3841MB Total, 207MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 4.15.0-135-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "18.04"
info: Session Type: x11
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.19.6
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_destroyed()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionGridMode_triggered()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_program_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_transitionRemove_clicked()
info: OBS 26.1.1 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 48000
    speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
error: X Error: GLXBadFBConfig, Major opcode: 155, Minor opcode: 34, Serial: 29
error: Failed to create OpenGL context.
error: Failed to create context!
error: device_create (GL) failed
error: Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 6485,01 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 5,389 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 2,478 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 300,642 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 28,175 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 67,982 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0,246 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0,399 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 67,208 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0,167 ms, median=0,713 ms, max=19,491 ms, 99th percentile=11,759 ms, 100% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0,004 ms, median=0,071 ms, max=0,155 ms, 99th percentile=0,145 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25,306 ms, median=25,836 ms, max=44,57 ms, 3,38983% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 96,6102% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 182
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on debian 10 was:
`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs` or at the end obs-studio if its the binary command for running obs

Source: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/failed-to-initialize-video-your-gpu-may-not-be-supported-or-your-graphics-drivers-may-need-to-be-updated.86284/